# Incorrect Django path to templates folder in settings.py

Tags: django, python-3.x, os.path

I am newly learning Django and was following the **Learn Django 1.11** Tutorial.

Here is my current project tree:

```
├── manage.py
├── muypicky
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── old_settings.py
│   ├── settings
│   │   ├── base.py      # Contains the settings (like shown in the tutorial)
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── requirements.txt
├── restaurants
└── templates           # Templates Folder
└── index.html
```

I am trying to add the path to the tempelates folder in the settings folder. But the error shown

> django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: .../muypicky/templates/index.html (Source does not exist)

Current setting.py file

```
TEMPLATES = [{
  'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], 
  },]
```

Looking at the error, the file path is wrong because it goes into /muypicky/tempelates which is incorrect. So how do I get to root folder and then into tempelates folder with the given file tree in setting.py (base.py).

Any further queries, just ask and many thanks in anticipation.

Comment: The only issue is the path to the templates folder in base.py (which is replacing settings.py). It works fine when I put the exact address to the templates folder like "home/user/desktop/venv/src/templates". Therefore, the only issue is that "os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')" looks for templates folder inside muypicky folder, when it should go back a directory.

Comment: My guess is that since you are using a settings folder you need to adjust `BASE_DIR` to go up one more folder.

Comment: Yes, that's correct but I am not sure how I can modify BASE_DIR "BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))". I tried different ideas but didn't work :(

Comment: Just add one more `os.path.dirname` to the chain.

Comment: already tried and didn't work. I don't know where os.path.dirname goes.

Comment: If the original was `os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))`, try `os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))`. What is the tutorial, by the way? If that's the issue they should say something about it.

Comment: tutorial is try django 1.11 on udemy.com

Comment: Soluction: BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```

and

```
TEMPLATES = [{'DIRS': [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
],},]
```

Addition of `os.path.dirname()` was wrapped to go back one folder

Comment: Cool. I watched the tutorial and he does say you need to adjust `BASE_DIR`, but I agree it's not clear, because you never see the full line.

Comment: Ye, a lot of the times, he says he will explain it later but often doesn't and it just becomes confusing.

Answer (score 0):

**settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads')
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [MEDIA_ROOT + '/'],#other app templates
    'APP_DIRS': True,#heremention yourapp/templates
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.template.context_processors.media'
        ],
    },
},
]
```

also can you look at document [djano template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/)

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem and was able to rectify with this:

```
TEMPLATES = [{
  ....

  'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/templates')],

  ....
```

**Dev Environment:** django 2.2, python 3.6

so i think you need to add `/` before the 'templates' string...

I also think this changes with django versions as i'm currently working on another project  that didn't require the trailing `/` before the 'templates' string on **django 2.1, python 3.6**. So i think this is worth trying out good luck