# os.path.join('BASE_DIR','template') problem

Tags: python, django, django-settings

When I run following code In settings.py

```js
TEMPLATES = [{
  'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
  'DIRS': [os.path.join('BASE_DIR','template')],
  'APP_DIRS': True,
  'OPTIONS': {
    'context_processors': [
      'django.template.context_processors.debug',
      'django.template.context_processors.request',
      'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
      'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    ],
  },
}, ]
```

it shows `error template not found` but when I execute following code in settings.py

```js
TEMPLATES = [{
  'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
  'DIRS': ['templates'],
  'APP_DIRS': True,
  'OPTIONS': {
    'context_processors': [
      'django.template.context_processors.debug',
      'django.template.context_processors.request',
      'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
      'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    ],
  },
}, ]
```

this works fine!

What does `os.path.join('BASE_DIR','template')` actually mean?

Comment: What exactly are you asking about? Did you check the documentation?

Comment: Also you have nested quotes: `['os.path.join('BASE_DIR','template') '],`

Comment: Please have a [look here](https://www.google.com/search?q=django+os.path.join(%27BASE_DIR%27,%27template%27)+site:stackoverflow.com) and start by removing the wrapper quotes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incorrect Django path to templates folder in settings.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45964127/incorrect-django-path-to-templates-folder-in-settings-py)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps:.

1. Declare 'import os' command in the top header section of settings.py file.
2. While defining DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'template')] , take the os from auto suggestions instead of typing.

Answer (score 0):

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': `enter code here`'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
```

its working I think

> os.path.join(DIR ) is using older version of DJANGO

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).